# How to backspace from command mode in Vim?

Tags: vim, backspace

If I'm in command mode, how do I backspace? Hitting the delete key on my Macbook just moves the cursor to the left one space. The fastest way I know to do this is `h, x`, but is there a better way, maybe with one key?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

x deletes to the right, X deletes to the left

This may be useful for you: [Vim Cheat Sheet](http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/11/27/vim-command-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Bleh, that file no longer exists. I've posted a copy of the contents: http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/11/27/vim-command-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 6):

In command mode, <kbd>r</kbd> might also be useful in some circumstances. It allows you to replace a single character under the cursor.

Typically I often use <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, to remove a character on a line without changing the indentation or alignement.

For example if you have the following code :

```
var anotherOne   = NULL;
var short1       = NULL;
var veryLongLong = NULL;
```

by using <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> on '1', your now have :

```
var anotherOne   = NULL;
var short        = NULL;
var veryLongLong = NULL;
```

instead of

```
var anotherOne   = NULL;
var short       = NULL;
var veryLongLong = NULL;
```

In the latter case, you must switch to insert mode to add another space.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, `x` is faster than `r, Space` and does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale : see my example

Comment: Oh, oops! :-) Now, I get it. Only took me a few years. ;-) Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Map it to <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> or your preferred shortcut in your vimrc. This works in command mode

```
nnoremap <silent> g<Space>  i<Space><Esc>
```

if you want to perform a move action after space, append the move action after Esc. e.g. below moves mouse to the left after space

```
nnoremap <silent> g<Space>  i<Space><Esc>j
```